# How Can I Embed Ruby into Bootstrap Input Form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I want to put this: <%= f.text_field :name %>

into the code below, but I keep getting an error. How can I properly embed it so that the code will work. Thanks!

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type= class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter Value">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need to be more specific. What error are you getting? Where, exactly, are you trying to insert this code? Where is `f` being instantiated?  Please include your controller entry and whatever errors you are encountering.

Comment: What error are you getting? You may want to compare the HTML generated by Rails with the HTML you're using here to see what the differences are. Rails does provide options for setting the `class` attribute (among) others on input elements.

Comment: Get rid of the input and replace it with `<%= f.text-field :name, class: 'form-control', id: 'exampleInputEmail1', placeholder: 'Enter Value' %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont' need the whole input section, just do this :

```
<%= f.text_field :name , :class=> "form-control"%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add bootstrap classes into your code via parameter `:class`

Answer (score 0):

Use [Formtastic Bootstrap](https://github.com/mjbellantoni/formtastic-bootstrap) it's a gem for rails, create forms with automatic bootstrap class

Answer (score 0):

'f' is not instantiated in you code so following code will raise error in the form-

```
<%= f.text_field :name %>
```

alternatively you can use this -

```
<%= text_field_tag :name,'', :placeholder => "Enter Value", :class=>"form-control", :id=>"exampleInputEmail1"  %>
```

this will not raise any error on embedding in the form.